# error - All mappings must have same table name - during EntityFramework.BulkInsert

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Everything works fine when I insert entities one by one like this:

```
blaDbContext.Blas.Add(new Bla());
blaDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, when I try to use [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/):

```
var list = new List<Bla>();
list.Add(new Bla());
blaDbContext.BulkInsert(list);
```

I am now getting:

```
"All mappings must have same table name."
```

The code worked previously and I am pretty sure that all entities map to unique table names. I did some searches but could not find any hints for what could be wrong.